# Query timeout increased but script fails to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i execute this script on my remote database it gives me query timeout error. I've increased the timeout on my database but still have this error. I've been told if i'm able to optimized the script to make it simple it might work.

```
SELECT TOP 8 MIN( CASE WHEN pic_alb_love.pic=users_pics.pic  

AND pic_alb_love.email =  'try@mail.com' THEN 'User'     ELSE 'Guest'   END)AS answer_one, 

MIN ( CASE WHEN favorites.pic=users_pics.pic  AND favorites.email = 'try@mail.com'  THEN 'good' ELSE 'Bad' 
  END)AS answer2, 

  (CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type) = 'wow'  THEN 'loaded' ELSE        

  CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type)= 'hey' THEN 'added' ELSE       

  CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type) = 'check'  THEN   'Changed'   END END END)as up_ans,     

  (CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type)  = 'sample1' THEN 'new'  ELSE    

  CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type)  = 'sample2' THEN 'existing'       ELSE   

  CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type)  = 'sample3' THEN 'Profile Picture'       END END END) as exs, 

  COUNT(DISTINCT users_pics.pic) as total,RTRIM (users_pics.wardrobe) as wardrobe, 



 fname,users_pics.wardrobe,

  MIN (make)as make,MIN (htags)as htags,  RTRIM (profile.profile_id) as profile_id,

  users_pics.email,profile.profile_pix, RTRIM (profile.gender) as gender, 

  users_pics.time_group,profile.fpage,up_user_id, MIN (u_pic_id) as u_pic_id, MIN (users_pics.pic) as pic
FROM users_pics 

LEFT join profile on users_pics.email = profile.email  

LEFT join favorites on users_pics.pic = favorites.pic  

LEFT JOIN pic_alb_love on users_pics.pic = pic_alb_love.pic 

left join friends on users_pics.email = friends.resp_email


WHERE req_email = 'try@mail.com' and pic_enable='enable' or pic_view='Public'  

GROUP BY users_pics.upload_type,profile.fname,profile.profile_id,users_pics.wardrobe, 

users_pics.email, profile.gender,users_pics.time_group,profile.profile_pix, profile.fpage,up_user_id


ORDER BY MIN (users_pics.u_pic_id) DESC
```

Comment: Make sure your query isn't blocked, you can choose it quering DMV or installing `sp_whoisactive`

Answer (score 0):

Increasing timeout can help, but you should also check if your query isn't blocked by others operations like INSERT/UPDATE or open transaction.

The easiest way is to install and use [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/) procedure.

Second you don't need to nest CASE like you did:

```
(CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type) = 'wow'  THEN 'loaded' ELSE        

  CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type)= 'hey' THEN 'added' ELSE       

  CASE WHEN RTRIM (users_pics.upload_type) = 'check'  THEN   'Changed'   END END END)as up_ans,
```

to

```
CASE RTRIM (user_pics.upload_type)
WHEN 'wow'   THEN 'loaded'
WHEN 'hey'   THEN 'added'
WHEN 'check' THEN 'changed'
ELSE NULL   /* or your value like 'unknown' */
END AS up_ans
```

Next thing: you `RTRIM` almost on every string value, you should sanitize your input during inserting, unless you need spaces/tabs/newline and so on.
This way your query won't need `RTRIM` and can utilize index if exists any.

```
/* New values */
INSERT INTO table_name(...) VALUES  (LTRIM(RTRIM(value...)))

/* Existing ones */
UPDATE table_name
SET col = LTRIM(RTRIM(col))
```

SQL Parser will understand **wall of text**, human will need time to do it.

I know we can argue about code style but remember you write code for people. Good readable code allow you to spot errors earlier and it is a hell easier to maintain in the future for you and your successors:

1) One selected value one line

2) The same order in SELECT and GROUP BY

3) Aggregated columns at end

4) You can use aliases no need for fully qualified names

5) No ambiguous column names, always specify from which table

6) SQL syntax UPPER CASE

7) Allign your code

Your query in more human readable from:

```
SELECT TOP 8  
   [up_user_id]   /* Always add from which table even if it is unique column name, because in future you may get ambigous column */
  ,[fname]
  ,[profile_id] = RTRIM(profile.profile_id)
  ,[up_ans]     = CASE RTRIM(users_pics.upload_type)
                    WHEN 'wow'   THEN 'loaded'
                    WHEN 'hey'   THEN 'added'
                    WHEN 'check' THEN 'changed'
                    ELSE NULL
                  END
  ,[exs]        = CASE RTRIM(users_pics.upload_type) 
                    WHEN 'sample1' THEN 'new'
                    WHEN 'sample2' THEN 'existing'
                    WHEN 'sample3' THEN 'Profile Picture'
                    ELSE NULL
                  END
  ,[wardrobe]       = RTRIM(users_pics.wardrobe)
  ,users_pics.email
  ,[gender]         = RTRIM(profile.gender)
  ,users_pics.time_group
  ,profile.profile_pix
  ,profile.fpage
  ,[answer_one]     = MIN(CASE 
                            WHEN pic_alb_love.pic=users_pics.pic THEN 'User'
                            ELSE 'Guest'
                          END)
  ,[answer2]        = MIN(CASE
                            WHEN favorites.pic = users_pics.pic  AND favorites.email = 'try@mail.com' WHEN 'good' 
                            ELSE 'Bad'
                         END)
  ,[total]          = COUNT(DISTINCT users_pics.pic)
  ,[make]           = MIN(make)
  ,[htags]          = MIN(htags)
  ,[u_pic_id]       = MIN(u_pic_id)
  ,[pic]            = MIN(users_pics.pic)
FROM users_pics     /* you can use alias like AS up */
LEFT JOIN profile
   ON users_pics.email = profile.email  
LEFT JOIN favorites 
   ON users_pics.pic   = favorites.pic  
LEFT JOIN pic_alb_love
   ON users_pics.pic   = pic_alb_love.pic 
LEFT JOIN friends
   ON users_pics.email = friends.resp_email
WHERE 
        req_email  = 'try@mail.com'
    AND pic_enable = 'enable'
    OR  pic_view   = 'Public'  
GROUP BY                     
     up_user_id
    ,profile.fname
    ,profile.profile_id
    ,users_pics.upload_type
    ,users_pics.wardrobe
    ,users_pics.email
    ,profile.gender
    ,users_pics.time_group
    ,profile.profile_pix
    ,profile.fpage
ORDER BY MIN(users_pics.u_pic_id) DESC
```

After you check that your query is not blocked during selecting data you can think about:

- checking indexes on your tables
- add WHERE condition to fetch smaller set, maybe you can use some `update_date > current_date - 2 weeks`
- think to optimize query because now it does grouping and ordering which needs time to complete.
- your `WHERE` condition, are you sure it shouldn't be:

.

```
 WHERE (req_email  = 'try@mail.com'
 AND pic_enable = 'enable')
 OR  pic_view   = 'Public'
```